# How to disable ERC connection notifications?

Tags: spacemacs, init-file, erc

My ERC irc client sends some very annoying messages that fill most of my screen, letting me know that I've connected. I'd like to turn these off.

I've tried setting a couple of variables and functions to `nil` without success: I expected `setq erc-enable-notifications nil` to do what I needed, but alas, it isn't the right place for this.

I'm using the [Spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) init with the [ERC layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+chat/erc/README.html).

[image]
These messages fill my screen every few minutes when my bouncer reconnects to me, so I suspect the repeated spam is the fault of my [ZNC](https://wiki.znc.in/ZNC) bouncer configuration.

Comment: While the *repeated* spam is probably my fault, the *initial* spam is not, and is still annoying.

Comment: I do not have an `erc-enable-notifications` variable in Emacs 26.2.  Where is that defined?

Comment: I am using spacemacs, this question is spacemacs-specific.

Comment: I have a Spacemacs config sitting around, and it doesn't have an `erc-enable-notifications` variable either.  What does `C-h v erc-enable-notifications` say?  As ERC is part of Emacs, and Spacemacs is Emacs plus additional libraries, I doubt there is anything in this question which *needs* to be spacemacs-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `erc-track-exclude-types`

For me, the original value was `("NICK" "333" "353")` and I have it set to:

```
("JOIN" "KICK" "NICK" "PART" "QUIT" "MODE" "333" "353")
```

The numeric values can be specific to the IRC daemon you are connected to, and might entail trial and error on your part to figure out which values are creating noise for you.

e.g. The following file (AFAICS) defines those recognised by the undernet (ircu) server (but the names and comments are pretty cryptic for the most part):

https://github.com/UndernetIRC/ircu2/blob/master/include/numeric.h

I'd be interested in pointers to other similar lists, and to any better documentation of the values (especially ones which are effectively standard).

Things I've located just now are:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812
- https://github.com/ngircd/ngircd/blob/master/doc/RFC.txt
- https://ircdocs.horse/
- https://defs.ircdocs.horse
- **https://defs.ircdocs.horse/defs/numerics.html** (at a glance, probably the best place to start)
- https://github.com/grawity/irc-docs
- https://github.com/ircdocs/irc-defs/blob/gh-pages/_data/numerics.yaml

Comment: Ignoring numerics is the way to go for preventing spam.

Answer (score 1):

If this is on account of `erc-notifications-mode` generating a notification because **your** nick was mentioned in the channel (on account of being listed in "*** Users on ..." message), then you'll have to dig into that functionality.

Or just disable the mode with `(erc-notifications-mode 0)` or similar to disable all notifications.

If that's the reason, then `erc-notifications-notify-on-match` will be triggering the message.  It looks at `erc-track-exclude` but I'm not sure whether `erc-track-exclude-types` has been factored in by that point.

The mode uses `erc-text-matched-hook` which is run from `erc-match-message`, and I'm not seeing any obvious use of the exclude-types in that sequence.

You might need to redefine or advise `erc-notifications-notify-on-match` to recognise and ignore these types of message.